# Active Current Menu - Adding class to child theme

Tags: menus, css

I am trying to add a feature to my site - when I am on a page, I would like that menu item to be highlighted (in a different color or just be bolded).

I have created a child theme (for portfolio-lite) and edited a few classes already, but I am having trouble adding this menu feature. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The default menu in `WordPress` already adds classnames for the current menu item, and if its a submenu, the parent will have a classname too as current-parent:

```
li.current-menu-item{
//here your CSS for the current menu item
}

li.current_page_parent{
//here your CSS for parent menu item of the current menu item
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi -
I have tried to find the current-menu css, but am unable to locate it anywhere in the style.css. This is the code in the css file -

Comment: /* General Menu Styles */

ul.menu,
ul.menu ul {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
ul.menu li {
 list-style: none;
 line-height: 1;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
ul.menu li li {
 font-size: 0.8em;
}
ul.menu li a,
ul.menu li a:link,
ul.menu li a:visited {
 display: block;
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 border-right: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 text-decoration: none;
 margin: 6px 0px;
 padding: 6px 8px;
}

Comment: ul.menu li a:hover,
ul.menu li a:active,
ul.menu li a:focus {
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
 border-right: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
 text-decoration: bold;
}
ul.menu li li a,
ul.menu li li a:link,
ul.menu li li a:visited {
 margin: 0px 18px 0px 0px;
 border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
ul.menu li li a::after {
 content: none;
 margin-left: 4px;
}

Comment: what would I update in order to have the page & subpage link bolded when you are on the page?

Comment: you cant locate it because there no CSS being applied to those right? add the CSS in my answer with `font-weight:bold` to make it bold

Comment: thanks, david - I ended up adding this to the code - ul.menu li.current-menu-item a,
ul.menu li.current-menu-item a:link,
ul.menu li.current-menu-item a:visited {
  text-decoration: underline;
} and it seemed to do the trick

Comment: =] np, if my answer helped you consider marking it.